# How can i drop the event if multiple id's are there

Tags: jquery

```
$(".draggable").bind('drag',function(event)
                    { 
                        data1=event.target.id; 
                    });
                $("#div1").on("dragover", function(event) 
                {
                        event.preventDefault();  
                        event.stopPropagation();
                });

                $("#div1").on("dragleave", function(event) 
                {
                         event.preventDefault();  
                         event.stopPropagation();
                });

                $("#div1").on('drop',function(event)
                                {
                                    event.preventDefault();
                                    var d=document.getElementById(data1).innerHTML;
                                    event.target.innerHTML=event.target.innerHTML+d;
                                });
```

In this we are dropping the dragged event to only one div tag...but if we have multiple div targets tags how to use drop event

Comment: use jQuery UI for drag and drop.

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: I have edited the question once check it